# Вывод шорткода на определенных страницах кастомных типов записей Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет. Такая штука... Есть сайт на Wordpress. У него создан кастомный тип записей, под названием Отзывы. В функциях был создан шорткод, чтобы при помощи `<?=do_shortcode('[reviews limit="3"]');?>` выводить на страницах несколько отзывов. Ниже код шорткода.

```
add_shortcode('reviews', 'reviews_func');
function reviews_func($atts) {
    $limit = -1;
    if (isset($atts['limit']) && (int)$atts['limit'] > 0) {
        $limit = $atts['limit'];
    }

    $reviews = get_reviews($limit);

    $html = '';
    if (!empty($reviews)) {
        $html .= '
            <div class="section">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="mb-5 text-center">Отзывы клиентов</h2>
                    <div class="row">
        ';

        foreach ($reviews as $item) {
            $html .= '
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
                    <div class="review-card">
                        <img src="'.$item['image'].'" class="review-card__img">
                        <div class="review-card__desc">
                            <p class="h5 text-normal text-center">'.$item['title'].'</p>
                            <p>'.strip_tags($item['content']).'</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ';
        }

        $html .= '</div>';

        if ($limit > 0) {
            $html .= '
                <div class="text-center mt-2">
                    <a href="/reviews/" class="btn btn-white mx-auto">Все реальные отзывы</a>
                </div>
            ';
        }

        $html .= '
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Раньше на всех страницах были одинаковые отзывы, но теперь заказчику понадобилось, на кастомных страницах Услуги, выводить разные отзывы. То есть, если услуга - выкуп авто на штрафстоянке, то выводить созданные отзывы, с определенным текстом, касаемые этой услуги.

Для этого я создал кастомные поля на страницах отзывов в виде чекбоксов, следующим образом:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_extra_fields', 1);
function my_extra_fields() {
    //add_meta_box( 'extra_fields', 'Дополнительные поля', 'extra_fields_box_func', 'post', 'normal', 'high'  );
    add_meta_box( 'extra_fields', 'Дополнительные поля', 'extra_fields_box_page_func', 'reviews', 'normal', 'high'  );
}

## html код блока для типа записей page
function extra_fields_box_page_func(){
   ?>
   <p><label><strong>На каких страницах услуг показывать отзыв?</strong></label><br></p>
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="extra[highprice]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[highprice]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'highprice', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп спецтехники по самой высокой цене</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[withoutdocs]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[withoutdocs]" value="1"   <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'withoutdocs',   1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто без документов</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[snow]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[snow]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'snow', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп снегоходов</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[carshare]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[carshare]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'carshare', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто из каршеринга</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[tradein]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[tradein]" value="1"   <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tradein',   1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто в трейдин</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[around]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[around]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'around', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто круглосуточно</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[taxi]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[taxi]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'taxi', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто из таксопарков</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[pts]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[pts]" value="1"   <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pts',   1), 1 )?> />   Выкуп авто без ПТС</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[fine]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[fine]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fine', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто со штрафстоянки</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[departure]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[departure]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'departure', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто с выездом</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[old]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[old]" value="1"   <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'old',   1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп старых авто</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[cash]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[cash]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cash', 1), 1 )?> /> Автовыкуп за наличные</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[new]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[new]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'new', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп новых авто</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[commerce]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[commerce]" value="1"   <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'commerce',   1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп коммерческих авто</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[moto]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[moto]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'moto', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп мотоциклов</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[parsing]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[parsing]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'parsing', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто на разбор</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[leasing]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[leasing]" value="1"   <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'leasing',   1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто из лизинга</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[faulty]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[faulty]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'faulty', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп неисправных авто</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[pledge]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[pledge]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pledge', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто в залоге</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[ban]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[ban]" value="1"   <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ban',   1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто в запрете</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[dtp]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[dtp]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dtp', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп авто после ДТП</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="extra[credit]" value="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra[credit]" value="1" <?php checked( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'credit', 1), 1 )?> /> Выкуп кредитных авто</label>
    </p>

   <?php
}
```

Это нужно, чтобы можно было в выбранном отзыве, поставить галочку напротив названия определенной Услуги, и этот отзыв появился на ее странице. Кастомные поля фунциклируют, но теперь мне нужно каким-то образом изменить код шорткода отзывов, чтобы он ловил зависимости от проставленных чекбоксов и выводил на странице конкретной услуги, только те отзывы, внутри которых будут проставлены галочки в чекбоксах. Я так понимаю нужно использовать конструкцию типа `if else`, вроде `if (leasing) { ... }`, но как конкретно и где все это использовать не могу догнать. Может вообще нужен другой подход. Памагити)))

Comment: Начни отсюда [No Shorthand PHP Tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/#no-shorthand-php-tags)

Comment: У меня как раз есть несколько месяцев для изучения php) спасибо